# Deserialization of list from XML in Blazor

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, blazor

I'm having some trouble deserializing a list of strings from XML in Blazor. The following code works fine in a standard C# app (count is 2) but fails in Blazor (count is 0).

```
            XNamespace SoapNS = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
            XNamespace TempNS = "http://tempuri.org/";
            var ResponseDoc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><GetPDFFormFieldNamesResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><GetPDFFormFieldNamesResult><string>aa</string><string>bb</string></GetPDFFormFieldNamesResult></GetPDFFormFieldNamesResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
            var ListRoot = ResponseDoc.Element(SoapNS + "Envelope")
                .Element(SoapNS + "Body")
                .Element(TempNS + "GetPDFFormFieldNamesResponse")
                .Element(TempNS + "GetPDFFormFieldNamesResult");
            var Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>),
                                               new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = ListRoot.Name.LocalName, Namespace = ListRoot.Name.NamespaceName });
            var List = Serializer.Deserialize(ListRoot.CreateReader()) as List<String>;
            Console.WriteLine(List.Count());
```

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/44mi7q7r shows the problem (in the browser console). Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: You are getting back JSON but trying to parse with XML.

Comment: Where is the JSON, please?

Comment: The resposnse is HTML (not xml) and the html is calling json scripts.

Comment: Why is the response HTML? And why the difference between the behaviour in Blazor and in a standard C# app?

Comment: No all server are the same.  Some will support only htmls responses and other will have various different types of responses.  The client in the request will specify the type of response it wants, and can only request the types the server supports.  Sometimes the type will be in the URL of the request as a property after the question mark and other times it will be a header in the request.  Other times the server only will give Xml in the response like in a Xml feed.

Comment: In the code I posted there is no server, though. I'm loading the XML from a string literal. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: There is always a server with an http connection.  One side of the connection is the client and the other side is the server.  The word Server has to meanings.  A Server at the application layer is a Machine/PC while at the transport layer (part of a socket) is the listener.  When you have a string in your code replace the Load(filename) method with Parse(string).

Comment: **Please** read the code I posted. There is no server, there is no HTTP connection, and I am already using the XDocument.Parse method.

Comment: The Blazor link you provided is using an HTTP connection with a webpage "Hello world".  The Hello World is the server and your c# is the client.  So it looks like your code works without a HTTP Connection and fails with a HTTP connection.